# Add a block to product page by custom module without editing magento default template

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to add a block to product page by using my custom module.
I do not want to modify any magento default files for this. I know it's possible by modifying the code in view.phtml template. Below is what I tried so far. I have copied the default magento view.phtml file in all module template folder as below. I included layout file inside config.xml of my module and written code for the block.

**view.phtml file I placed under each template of module folder.
app/desifn/frontend/default/default/template/mymodule/view.phtml**

**config.xml file of module -**

```
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <modulename>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Module_name</module>
                <frontName>modulefrontname</ntNafrome>
            </args>
        </modulename>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <modulename module="module_name">
                <file>module.xml</file>         
            </modulename>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

**This file is under -** 
**app/desifn/frontend/default/default/layout/modulename.xml**

```
<reference name="product.info">
                <block type="module_name/product_view" name="product_list">
                    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="module_name/sp_category/status">
                        <template>modulename/product/view.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Node modulename is invalid (wrong closing tag)

```
    <updates>
        <modulename module="module_name">
            <file>module.xml</file>         
        </module>
    </updates>
```

and also template paths do not match

```
/mymodule/view.phtml
```

and

```
modulename/product/view.phtml
```

**But back to your initial Question:**

view.phtml of default template does not contain getChildHtml without any parameters. So the only way to inject custom stuff is to use a block of type core/text_list, which is "product.info.simple.extra". All you need is to make use of `before` or `after` attributes in your xml layout.

Comment: Hi , Path is correct as you mentioned "modulename/product/view.phtml". for all themes